# How can I group from a column created in a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I group by a derived column in the select statement?

I have a query:

```
select sum(hours) as summedhours, vendoremployeeid, vendorUserName, lineofbusiness, timesheetdate, 
case 
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =1 then dateadd(weekday,4,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =2 then dateadd(weekday,3,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =3 then dateadd(weekday,2,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =4 then dateadd(weekday,1,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =5 then dateadd(weekday,0,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =6 then dateadd(weekday,6,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =7 then dateadd(weekday,5,timesheetdate)
end 
as FridaysGrouping
from viewProjects
group by FridaysGrouping, vendoremployeeid, vendorusername, lineofbusiness, timesheetdate
order by FridaysGrouping asc
```

When I run the above, it gives me an error that states column name "FridaysGrouping' doesn't exist. I believe this is because the order of execution for an sql server is :
from > where  > group by  > having > select > order by

What is the best way to group by the derived column above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the same computed column in `group by`

```
select sum(hours) as summedhours, vendoremployeeid, vendorUserName, lineofbusiness, timesheetdate, 
case 
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =1 then dateadd(weekday,4,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =2 then dateadd(weekday,3,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =3 then dateadd(weekday,2,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =4 then dateadd(weekday,1,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =5 then dateadd(weekday,0,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =6 then dateadd(weekday,6,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =7 then dateadd(weekday,5,timesheetdate)
end 
as FridaysGrouping
from viewProjects
group by FridaysGrouping, vendoremployeeid, vendorusername, lineofbusiness, timesheetdate,
case 
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =1 then dateadd(weekday,4,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =2 then dateadd(weekday,3,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =3 then dateadd(weekday,2,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =4 then dateadd(weekday,1,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =5 then dateadd(weekday,0,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =6 then dateadd(weekday,6,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =7 then dateadd(weekday,5,timesheetdate)
end
order by FridaysGrouping asc
```

or use `CTE`. Find the computed column in `CTE` then do the `group by` in outer `select`. which is more readable

```
with cte as
(
select hours , vendoremployeeid, vendorUserName, lineofbusiness, timesheetdate, 
case 
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =1 then dateadd(weekday,4,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =2 then dateadd(weekday,3,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =3 then dateadd(weekday,2,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =4 then dateadd(weekday,1,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =5 then dateadd(weekday,0,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =6 then dateadd(weekday,6,timesheetdate)
when datepart(weekday,timesheetdate) =7 then dateadd(weekday,5,timesheetdate)
end 
as FridaysGrouping
from viewProjects
)
SELECT Sum(hours) summedhours,
       vendoremployeeid,
       vendorUserName,
       lineofbusiness,
       timesheetdate,
       FridaysGrouping
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY FridaysGrouping,
          vendoremployeeid,
          vendorusername,
          lineofbusiness,
          timesheetdate
ORDER  BY FridaysGrouping ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem few days ago and I solved it by using `Inner Join`.

```
Select ... , col1, ... From ...
Inner Join
(Select ... as col1, ... From ...  --newly created column here can be used outside as col1 directly.
)tb1
On ...
Where ...
Group by ...
Order by ...
```

Comment: What will be your `ON` condition in the `JOIN`? Also, this is not an optimal and best solution.

Comment: Agreed with the downvote. This not only leaves out important details, but is also inefficient. It looks like you really want to use a derived table expression or a CTE, but instead used an inner join. Wrong choice.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I didn't know that join is inefficient. For the `ON` condition, you use the column which is unique in the table. @siride

Comment: @L16H7: you're joining against the same table, necessitating two scans/seeks instead of just one. It's possible the query optimizer would figure this out, but I wouldn't count on it. I've never tested because I've never done something like that.

Comment: What you're really talking about it wrapping the query in a derived table. You're on the right track but just get rid of the `INNER JOIN` and `ON`. At that point you can refer to columns of `tb1` by name.